# Copied all folders from a secondary drive to a peripheral drive, signifigant size difference?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive, data-transfer

I recently bought a drive docking station for drives to make some back ups to drives not in my system. In my computer I currently have a 256GB SSD for my OS (Windows 7) and a 2TB HDD for storage.

I plugged a 500GB HDD into the docking station and copied all the files and folders (~234GB) from my storage drive and pasted it to the 500GB HDD. After the transfer completed I ended up with a large difference in size (~100GB) for the total copied data.

[image]

For the life of me I cannot figured out why the size dropped so much. Any explanations?

Possibly why the drive is in use some files are uncompressed for use but upon copying then are compressed?

EDIT: As per the first comment I selected all the files and folders on the drive and looked at the properties. I guess the data is the same size.

[image]

So the question now is, why the differences in the size from the way I compared them initially?

Comment: I wonder if the cluster size is larger on the new drive. You might want to get the stats from the same place so we can see file count and usage for the path, not the drive.

Comment: While cluster sizes can make a big difference they can't make this difference.  He's got about 100,000 entries, a 100gb difference would require a cluster size of a megabyte--something that I don't think is an option.  I think it's much more likely there were hidden files that weren't copied.

Comment: Usually there are hidden system files on this drive that weren't copied. If you have moved your pagefile and hibernation file, or  windows System Restore points. Try to enable Show hidden files and folders , and to disable Hide protected operating system files from the folder options.